Question about auto re-issue Access token in Django (simple jwt)
Hello I have a question about JWT in backend django, so I'm leaving a question. (I'm using Simple-jwt package.)
Currently, when the user logs in, both access and refresh tokens are being sent to the response body. (I'm trying to send refresh tokens to the header because there's a security problem.)
At this time, when the access token expires, I know the procedure to reissue it through refresh, but I don't know how django will handle it automatically.
I wanted to go to the procedure of reissuance before the expiration time of access at the front(web/app), but there is a problem that the access token increases indefinitely.
When the front sends a general API request, I know that if client send both access and refresh, the access token will expire through the IsAuthenticated procedure at the back server, and I understand that it automatically reissues the access token through refresh and performs the previously requested API.
So I tried Googling this, but I didn't see the code that automatically reissued it, only sending it to the endpoint (/jwt-token-auth/refresh/) provided by default.
However, if I get caught in IsAuthenticated, the server spit out the error because it's invalid token, how do I automatically reissue it and come back to perform the requested api?
Also, I wonder where should the refresh token be located when I send the request... Is there any setting way?

It's the clients responsibility to rotate the access token when required the server doesn't (and probably shouldn't) be auto-rotating it.

@AbdulAzizBarkat
When FE handles access token expiration manually, they need expired_at data, should BE send expired_at data when the user logs in? OR Should FE decodes access token and take expired_at data manually?

That's supposed to be in the token though as a claim? The frontend should be able to read / parse that pretty easily given that JWT's are usually just base64 encoded.

@AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you for answering the question. It help me a lot in deciding.
